# Writing String gives me error, writing image not

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
            let image = UIImage(data: downloadedImage!)


            let convertImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
            let pathUIDImage = self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(playersUID + "Image")
            try? convertImage!.write(to: pathUIDImage) //working


            let playersUIDImageVersion = "1"
            var pathUIDImageVersion = self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(playersUID + "ImageVersion")
            try? playersUIDImageVersion.write(to: pathUIDImageVersion) //error
```

The error is:

Cannot convert value of type "URL" to expected instrument type "inout_"

When I replace try? playersUIDImageVersion to try? convertImage! the error is gone. Is there a difference between writing different types of values to the directory?  Thank you. Below the function getDocumentsDirectory

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `write` function of `String` is different, it requires additional parameters `atomically` and `encoding`.

```
try? playersUIDImageVersion.write(to: pathUIDImageVersion, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
```

In such a case retype the function and see what Xcode suggests for code completion.

Besides it's highly recommended to use always an appropriate file extension (`.png`, `.txt`).

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. What do you mean with using appropriate file extensions? Where and how would I add them?

Comment: Your image is supposed to be named `playersUID + "Image.png"` and the string `playersUID + "ImageVersion.txt"`